# Force pip to skip or ignore bad hash on download cache

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Wondering if anyone knows a workaround to force pip to either completely skip hash checks or ignore bad sums when installing from a download cache? Install cmd is:

```
pip.exe install --target=C:\WHERE_I_WANT_INSTALLED --download-cache=C:\MY_DL_CACHE mitmproxy
```

Mitmproxy requires a specific version of pillow, and in that specific version there just happens to be a defined C function whos signature collides with another function in an include within Mingw x86_64. I'm not changing out my toolchain, as anyone who uses mingw on windows knows, it's a disgustingly painful process to find and keep a stable version.

Anyway, I've posted the question as a bug report on pips github but I thought I'd pose the question here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the answer in the very last place I would ever think to look: [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#fast-local-installs).

So basically you run a few commands to have pip download everything that is required for what you're trying to install. In this case, its was mitmproxy. So first I grabbed the requirements.txt file for mitmproxy, and dropped it into a dir. Commands to download packages were:

```
pip install --download C:\MY_SECRET_PATH\mitm\dl-cache six
pip install --download C:\MY_SECRET_PATH\mitm\dl-cache mock
pip install --download C:\MY_SECRET_PATH\mitm\dl-cache itsdangerous
pip install --download C:\MY_SECRET_PATH\mitm\dl-cache cryptography
pip install --download C:\MY_SECRET_PATH\mitm\dl-cache mitmproxy
```

Now, everything required for mitm-proxy is stored in the provided path. We then supply this path and a couple of other flags to the command for installing what we're after, again mitmproxy. To make things more interesting, I'm installing all of this stuff in a custom dir. So that command is as follows:

```
pip.exe install mitmproxy --no-index --target=C:\MY_SECRET_PATH\mitm --find-links=C:\MY_SECRET_PATH\mitm
```

So we're basically telling pip to install the selected package and all its deps offline, not checking pypy and therefore skipping hash checks. You're then obviously free to modify the sources of the packages you've downloaded, as I have.

Comment: Documentation should be your first place not "last".